# SelectedRow count always equal 0 on one method, but works fine on another

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a project to create a customer & appointment application.
I have a datagridview that pulls data from a database (works fine), and allows me to add/delete/update appointments.
I have the datagridview set to `FullRowSelect`, and `MultiSelect` set to false, so users can only select one row.
After selecting a row, one can update or delete the row (and record(s)) from the database.

When you select a row, and click delete, it asks for confirmation, then deletes the row:

```
    private void deleteAppointmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?", "delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(SqlUpdater.conString);
                MySqlCommand delcmd = new MySqlCommand();

                if (appointmentCalendar.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
                {
                    delcmd.Connection = c;
                    c.Open();
                    delcmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE 
                    appointmentId = " + 
                    appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value + ";";
                    delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    c.Close();
                    appointmentCalendar.Rows.RemoveAt(appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Index);
                    MessageBox.Show("Appointment Deleted");
                }
```

When I try to update a row, using:

```
   private void updateAppointmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (appointmentCalendar.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a row to update");
            }
            else
            {

                UpdateAppointment updateAppointment = new UpdateAppointment();

                updateAppointment.customerIdBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                updateAppointment.customerNameBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                updateAppointment.typeBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                updateAppointment.startTimeBox.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                updateAppointment.endTimeBox.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());

                updateAppointment.Show();
            }                            
        }
```

It always comes back with the "Please select a row to update" messagebox, as if the row count was zero upon pressing the button.

Any ideas?

Comment: `appointmentCalendar.SelectedRows.Count != 0` shoudn't it be `==` ?

Comment: *slaps head* I didn't even notice that. Good call.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `delcmd.CommandText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Serg pointed out, I was using != (not equal) instead of == (equal to).

Thanks!